# How to use a constructor if it says : no default constructor for ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

PLease help as to what I should do, in this case.

WordAdapter java file
[image]

Comment: maybe you add a default constructor?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: Just click on the error and press `Alt`+`Enter` and Android Studio will automatically fix it for you or show you possible fixes

Comment: Hello you did..as we said..?

Answer (score 0):

[image]add this method

```
 public void WordAdapter(Context context){
 }
```

Comment: i add a picture in answer , here is all contractor of ArrayAdapter

Comment: @GaziRimon thanks for improvement

Answer (score 0):

Add this **Constructor** In your Adapter:

```
public WordAdapter(){
}
```

**if Required then add below**

```
public WordAdapter(Context mContext){
}
```

Hope this will Helps.